# Finding correlation coefficient between transformed random variables.

Tags: probability, independence, exponential-distribution

If we have three iid random variables $X_1$,$X_2$,$X_3$ with common pdf f(x)= $e^{-x}$ for x greater than 0. How can we calculate the correlation coefficient between $Y_1$=$X_1$/$X_2$ and $Y_2$=$X_1+X_2$?

I know that the pdf for $Y_1$ should be $1/(1+y_1)^2$ and pdf for $Y_2$ should be $y_2e^{-y_2}$. But I do not know how to go further. Do I need to get the E($Y_1Y_2$) and variance of  $Y_1,Y_2$ for this problem? Or are there any other ways to do this?

Comment: You do not seem to use $X_3$ - is this a typo?

Comment: $X_3$ will be used in another question and I think I could figure that one out. So I just do not mention it here.

Comment: Given $Y_2=y_2$, I would have thought the conditional distribution of $X_1$ would be uniform on $[0,y_2]$ and similarly $X_2$.  So I suspect $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are independent

Comment: But that does not imply their covariance or correlation is $0$.  I suspect $E[Y_1]$ is infinite (your density is that of the absolute value of a Cauchy distribution) and so the correlation cannot be calculated

Comment: "Given $_2=_2$, I would have thought the conditional distribution of $_1$ would be uniform on [0,$_2$]".Could you give more detail on this statement? Why is that true? And why would correlation not equal 0 if they are independent?

Comment: On the conditional uniform distribution, it comes from other questions.  On correlation, this is defined involving expectations and square roots of variances, which breaks if any of the values are infinite or undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The covariance $\operatorname{Cov}(Y_1,Y_2)$ is not defined because $E(Y_1)=\int_0^\infty \frac{x}{(1+x)^2}\,dx=\infty$. As a result the correlation $\operatorname{Corr}(Y_1,Y_2)$ is also not defined.

However, one can show using a change of variables that $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are independently distributed since their joint density factors as the product of two marginal densities. Or if you like a more statistical argument, then suppose $X_1,X_2$ are i.i.d Exponential with rate $\lambda(>0)$. The independence follows from [Basu's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basu%27s_theorem) since $Y_2=X_1+X_2$ is a [complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completeness_(statistics)) [sufficient statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufficient_statistic) for $\lambda$ and $Y_1=\frac{\lambda X_1}{\lambda X_2}$ is an [ancillary statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancillary_statistic). Independence of $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ would have implied $\operatorname{Corr}(Y_1,Y_2)=0$ if the correlation was defined.

Comment: that makes sense, thanks a lot!